# how do I pass in a object function into another using the arguments given

Tags: javascript, object, destructuring

I am trying to pass in an 'order' function to 'orderDelivery' function through objects to synchronize with the order instead of hard coding it at the bottom

```
const restaurant = {
  name: 'Classico Italiano',
  location: 'Via Angelo Tavanti 23, Firenze, Italy',
  categories: ['Italian', 'Pizzeria', 'Vegetarian', 'Organic'],
  starterMenu: ['Focaccia', 'Bruschetta', 'Garlic Bread', 'Caprese Salad'],
  mainMenu: ['Pizza', 'Pasta', 'Risotto'],
  openingHours: {
    thu: {
      open: 12,
      close: 22,
    },
    fri: {
      open: 11,
      close: 23,
    },
    sat: {
      open: 0,
      close: 24,
    },
  },
  order: function (starterIndex, mainIndex) {
    return [this.starterMenu[starterIndex], this.mainMenu[mainIndex]];
  },
  
  orderDelivery: function({starterIndex, mainIndex, time, address}) {
    // ({starterIndex, mainIndex}) = this.order(2,1) attempt 1 - destructuring
    // this.order(2,1) attempt 2 - logging shows correct order but undefined
    console.log(`Order received! ${this.starterMenu[starterIndex]} and ${this.mainMenu[mainIndex]} will be delivered to ${address} at ${time}`);
  }
};

// const myOrder = restaurant.order(2, 1); attempt 3  

restaurant.orderDelivery({
  time: '22:30',
  address: 'Via del Sole, 21',
  // mainIndex: myOrder[0], attempt from 3
  // starterIndex: 2, hard code
});
```

I  have tried destructuring but something tells me I would have to use the order function in the orderDelivery function that is outside the object but I am not really sure how. I tried assigning the order function outside and pass it through the orderDelivery but same undefined result.

Comment: The result is undefined becase you have commented the arguments `mainIndex` and `starterIndex` in calling `orderDelivery` function

Comment: my comments are my attempts to not confuse the actual code. still undefined

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to build a `class` rather than regular Object - but here is how to do it without Classes:

```js
function genericOrder(starterIndex, mainIndex) 
{
    return [this.starterMenu[starterIndex], this.mainMenu[mainIndex]];
}

function genericDelivery(parameters) 
{
  console.log(`Order received! ${this.starterMenu[parameters.starterIndex]} and ${this.mainMenu[parameters.mainIndex]} will be delivered to ${parameters.address} at ${parameters.time}`);
}

const restaurant = {
  name: 'Classico Italiano',
  location: 'Via Angelo Tavanti 23, Firenze, Italy',
  categories: ['Italian', 'Pizzeria', 'Vegetarian', 'Organic'],
  starterMenu: ['Focaccia', 'Bruschetta', 'Garlic Bread', 'Caprese Salad'],
  mainMenu: ['Pizza', 'Pasta', 'Risotto'],
  openingHours: {
    thu: {
      open: 12,
      close: 22,
    },
    fri: {
      open: 11,
      close: 23,
    },
    sat: {
      open: 0,
      close: 24,
    },
  },
};

restaurant.order = genericOrder.bind(restaurant);
restaurant.orderDelivery = genericDelivery.bind(restaurant);

const myOrder = restaurant.order(2, 1);

restaurant.orderDelivery({
  time: '22:30',
  address: 'Via del Sole, 21',
  mainIndex: 0,
  starterIndex: 2,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `undefined` because when you call `restaurant.orderDelivery()` you must pass params spelled in exact way you defined them in `orderDelivery` function. This is how object destructuring works.

You are basically defined a function which accepts an `object` with some desired properties as argument, so you have to pass this object with its properties in order to work. If a property is not supplied, the value of it is going to be `undefined`.

Another point is your `order`, which returns an array composed by an element of starterMenu and one of mainMenu, so doing myOrder[0] in your case returns a string, not an index (which I guess is what you want)

If you want the index of that items you should use `Array.indexOf()` on the right array containing the item you are looking for:

```
restaurant.orderDelivery({
    time: '22:30',
    address: 'Via del Sole, 21',
    starterIndex: restaurant.starterMenu.indexOf(myOrder[0]),
    mainIndex: restaurant.mainMenu.indexOf(myOrder[1]),
});
```

This kinda works but is a little bit tricky. You could move this searching logic inside `orderDelivery` function and instead of `starterIndex` and `mainIndex` you directly pass `order()` output:

```
  orderDelivery: function({orderedItems, time, address}) {
     const starterIndex = restaurant.starterMenu.indexOf(orderedItems[0])
     const mainIndex = restaurant.mainMenu.indexOf(orderedItems[1])

     console.log(`Order received! ${this.starterMenu[starterIndex]} and 
     ${this.mainMenu[mainIndex]} will be delivered to ${address} at 
     ${time}`);
  }
```

So you can call restaurant.orderDelivery() in this way:

```
const myOrder = restaurant.order(2, 1);

restaurant.orderDelivery({
   time: '22:30',
   address: 'Via del Sole, 21',
   orderedItems: myOrder
});
```